# VS 2022 Naming Style - generic parameter specification

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My VS 2022 naming style requires pascalCase for parameters; they must start with a lowercase character.  This works great until I use generics,such as `public List<T> GetAll<T>()`. I would actually prefer the T stay uppercase, but the compiler is treating the generic as just another parameter and raises a naming style error .  I've looked through the specifications and nothing seems to correlate with generics.  Is there any way to specify a naming style for generic parameters separate from other parameters?

Comment: In my naming styles, if a parameter does not start with a lower case, it is treated as a compile time error.  I'm using C# but I wasn't sure that was relevant to a question about a naming style in VS.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @mkrieger1 IDE1006 - Naming rule violation: The first word, 'T', must begin with a lower case character.

In my naming style, I've required parameters to start with a lower case, showing an IDE error in the VS Error List if they do not.  Changing the rule to a suggestion gets rid of the error, but then the naming convention is not enforced.  I want to use a different naming style rule for generic parameters.